# The little eye on the right hand side when logging in passwords

Tags: windows-7, windows, internet, windows-explorer

I just finished reading an answer to this question - but why is this happening? I had someone come out to fix my internet explorer - which was running super slow due to a recent install of HP printer software - and now I have the little black eye.  Could my tech person have put in spy ware to capture all of our passwords?
Thanks, Suzanne

Comment: It's for internet explorer 10. It's not spyware

Answer (score 2):

This is new on Windows I think since Windows 8 was launched. Anyways the ‘Eye’ Symbol is present there so that you can see what you typed in the password field. So, do not click on it when someone is looking.

**If you want to remove it, just follow the simple steps:**

1. Open **Run** Prompt (Win + R)
2. Enter **gpedit.msc**.
3. **Local Group Policy editor** will open
4. Go to **Computer Configuration** Expand **Administrative Templates–>Windows Components–>Credential User Interface**
5. Open **Do not display the password reveal button** and **click** on **Enabled option**
6. The option is disabled.